# Flask subprocess cannot see changes in DB

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, multiprocessing

Im using Flask app with long-running worker proccess and this process cannot see changes in DB.

**main.py**

In this file I create Flask app and start the process.

```
from paas.app_factory import create_app()

app = create_app()

from .controllers.resource_controller import *

from .worker import create_resource, delete_resource
from multiprocessing import Process
from flask import current_app

with app.app_context():
    create_proc = Process(target=create_resource, args=(current_app._get_current_object(),)).start()
```

**worker.py**

Worker every 20 sec checks if new resources appeared in DB and if so, it will process them

```
def create_resources(app):
    with app.app_context():
        while True:
            resource = get_resource_to_create()
            if not resource:
                print("Wait for resource to create...")
                time.sleep(20)
                continue
            create_resource.....
```

**resource_controller.py**

After application started I added some resource to db. Problem is, that through the second route I can get resource from db, but worker.py sees nothing in DB.

```
from .main import app

@app.route('resource/<resource>', method=POST)
create_resource():
    write_resource_to_db(resource)

@app.route('resources')
get_resources():
    select_all_resources_from_db()
```

I believe there is some misunderstanding of application context from my side, but I cannot figure it out. Help would be really nice.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Let's say `get_resource_to_create()` and `select_all_resources_from_db()` are the same function inside.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in

```
def create_resources(app):
    with app.app_context():
        while True:
```

Loop was in the app context == in one transaction, so it worked like that:

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ...;
SELECT ...;
SELECT ...;
...
```

So there was no chance to get fresh data.

If I switched the lines,

```
def create_resources(app):
    while True:
        with app.app_context():
```

then after one cycle ends, there is a commit and new transaction with fresh data.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... ;
COMMIT;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT ... ;
COMMIT;
...
```